# This simple Python Fraction Adder is not fully robust and is recieving errors. How can it be improved?

Tags: python, math, stored-procedures, console, arithmetic-expressions

I have written a fraction adder in Python for my computer science class. However, I am running into problems with the final answer reduction procedure.

The procedure uses the "not equal" comparison operator **!=** at the start of a **for** loop to test whether, when dividing the numerator and denominator, there will be a remainder. If there will be a remainder (numerator % denominator ≠ 0), the procedure executes: each gets divided by **n**, then **n** increments and the **for** loop runs again. This continues until they divide evenly into each other.

Firstly, I am recieving a syntax error:

```
python FractionAdder.py 2 4 6 8
File "FractionAdder.py", line 23
for ansnum % n != 0 and ansdenom % n != 0:
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Secondly, the **for** loop is not fully robust. My intended purpose was to have it reduce the final answer to its simplest form, but right now, it is only continuing to increment **n** and reduce until the numerator and denominator divide into each other evenly. This is a problem: 3 divides evenly into 6, but 3/6 is not in its simplest form. May I have some suggestions as to how to improve the robustness of my procedure, such that **n** continues to increment and the loop keeps cycling until the simplest form has been achieved? (Is there a better way to structure my conditional to achieve this?)

Full Code:

```
import sys
num1 = int(sys.argv[1])
denom1 = int(sys.argv[2])
num2 = int(sys.argv[3])
denom2 = int(sys.argv[4])

n = 1

# Find common denominators and adjust both fractions accordingly.
while denom1 != denom2:
    denom1 = denom1 * denom2
    num1 = num1 * denom2

    denom2 = denom2 * denom1
    num2 = num2 * denom2

# Add the numerators and set the ansdenom (denom1 and denom2 should be equal by this point if LCD function worked)
ansnum = num1 + num2
ansdenom = denom1

# Reduce the answer.
n = 2
for ansnum % n != 0 and ansdenom % n != 0:
    ansnum = ansnum / n
    ansdenom = ansdenom / n
    n += 1

print("The sum of the two fractions is:" + str(ansnum) + "//" + str(ansdenom))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you need a `while` loop and not `for` in line 23.

Answer (score 2):

The error you see is derived by the wrong usage of `for` where `while` is the right type of loop (`for` is for iteration, `while` for condition).

Nevertheless, your logic at deciding the common denominators is flawed, and leads to an infinite loop. Please read about [least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple), and consider the following pseudocode for determining the "new" numerators:

```
lcm = lcm(den1, den2)
num1 *= lcm / den1
num2 *= lcm / den2
```

Comment: Finding the least common multiple of the divisors is irrelevant, as the new numerator may still be an integer multiple of the LCM divisor. Ex: 3/6 + 6/12 - LCM of divisors is 12, result is 6/12 + 6/12 = 12/12, not reduced. The proper procedure is to calculate the new numerator and denominator, find the GCD, and divide through, as shown in my code below.

Comment: @HughBothwell I've not even looked at the rest of the code, since it wasn't **the question**. He may not be using the best method, but still, he is clearly **learning**. If you tried to fix every trainee code, you'd just take away their motivation to improve by themselves

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write a greatest-common-denominator finder, and your terminating condition is wrong. [Euclid's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) repeatedly takes takes the modulo difference of the two numbers until the result is 0; then the next-to-last result is the GCD. The standard python implementation looks like

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a
```

There is an implementation already in the standard library, `math.gcd`.

```
from math import gcd
import sys

def add_fractions(n1, d1, n2, d2):
    """
    Return the result of n1/d1 + n2/d2
    """
    num   = n1 * d2 + n2 * d1
    denom = d1 * d2
    div   = gcd(num, denom)
    return num // div, denom // div

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 5:
        print("Usage: {} num1 denom1 num2 denom2".format(sys.argv[0]))
    else:
        n1, d1, n2, d2 = [int(i) for i in sys.argv[1:]]
        num, denom = add_fractions(n1, d1, n2, d2)
        print("{}/{} + {}/{} = {}/{}".format(n1, d1, n2, d2, num, denom))
```

Comment: Looks like too many answers like this one are popping here lately. This barely answers the question; let alone it doesn't even specify a clear answer to *the question asked* (aka why isn't this working), it is also suggesting a brand new way to implement OPs requirement, disregarding OPs' code and state of mind; SO isn't a tutorial, neither a code writing service, so please do not answer that way to questions not under these catgories. This would come as **answer** only on code review

Comment: For the same way "document" and "abstract" (which are merely recommendations) should come by no more than comment, and surely do not belong as an answer

Comment: @Uriel: it was poorly phrased, and I have improved it. On the other hand it accurately and efficiently solves the problem he is working on, rather than sending him off in the wrong direction.

Comment: 1. I did not send him the wrong direction. 2. Cheers for knowing to write accurate and *efficient (ahm you are using python)* code! but that's not OP asked you for